# How do I import quickgraph library to my project

Tags: c#

I'v got quickgraph from http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/releases/view/20160
but I couldn't figure out how to import it because there wasn't any .dll files in the package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Release Notes

QuickGraph is available exclusively through NuGet. Learn more about NuGet at http://nuget.org.

```
PM> Install-Package QuickGraph
```